# Toggle change 2 DIV width at a time + localStorage

Tags: javascript, css, switch-statement, toggle

```js
function myFunction() {
   var element = document.getElementById("one1");
   element.classList.toggle("one2");
   var element = document.getElementById("two1");
   element.classList.toggle("two2");
}
```

```css
<style>
#section{margin-left:50px;
margin-right:50px
}
#monbouton{float:right;
font-size:25px;
width:50px;
height:50px;
background-color:#F1F1F1;
border:1px solid ##F1F1F1
}
#one1{
float:left;
width:40%;
height:100px;
border:1px solid blue
}
.one2{
width:10% !important;
height:200px;
border:1px solid red !important;
}
.one2 #afairedisparaitre{display:none
}
#two1{float:right;
width:59%;
height:100px;
border:1px solid green
}
.two2{width:89% !important
}
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="section">
<div id="one1">
<button id="monbouton" onclick="myFunction()">&#8596;</button>
    <div id="afairedisparaitre">This is DIV #one1<br />
    Button toggle to CLASS .one2<br />
  and reverse</div>
</div>
  <div id="two1">This is DIV #two1<br />
  Button toggle to CLASS .two2<br />
  and reverse</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to make the leftside of my website shrink, so that the users can have a wider rightside if they find it more confortable.
What I am missing is a way that would keep the choice all over the site, when an other page is loaded, until the user clicks again. Maybe the solution would be a few more lines in js with "localStorage" ? I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Sorry I guess I deleted my answer by mistake ...

I wanted to thank you warmthly for your answer. I tried to implement your suggestions but it not working, I might have forgotten something... Please find here a link, because it needs 2 pages to see if it keeps the user's choice even after loading a new page https://www.lepointdufle.net/toggl1.htm

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made your CSS a bit better. Now we need to toggle only one class `.with_toggle` for `#section`.

It can sow errors here, in Snippet, but will fork fine on [Codepan](https://codepen.io/focus-style/pen/QWyBNMr), see please. Try to switch it and reload the page on Codepan.

```js
// checking if our storage is not empty
if (localStorage.toggled != '') {
  // set class to #section form storage value
  document.getElementById("section").classList.toggle(localStorage.toggled);
}

function myFunction() {
  if (localStorage.toggled != "with_toggle") {
    document.getElementById("section").classList.add("with_toggle");
    localStorage.toggled = "with_toggle";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("section").classList.remove("with_toggle");
    localStorage.toggled = "";
  }
}
```

```css
#section {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

#monbouton {
  float: right;
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  border: 1px solid #F1F1F1;
}

#one1 {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.with_toggle #one1 {
  width: 10%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.with_toggle #one1 #afairedisparaitre {
  display: none;
}

#two1 {
  float: right;
  width: 59%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.with_toggle #two1 {
  width: 89%;
}
```

```html
<div id="section">
  <div id="one1">
    <button id="monbouton" onclick="myFunction()">&#8596;</button>
    <div id="afairedisparaitre">This is DIV #one1<br /> Button toggle to CLASS .one2<br /> and reverse</div>
  </div>
  <div id="two1">This is DIV #two1<br /> Button toggle to CLASS .two2<br /> and reverse</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer !!
The thing is that it doesn't "remember" the last choice when loading a new page.
Since I need 2 pages to have it work, I allow myself to send you this link so that you can figure out better https://www.lepointdufle.net/toggl1.htm

Comment: It works accross those two pages fine. but at some reason it doesn't add ore remove class one the first click. Need couple of minutes to figure out why.

Comment: here `<div id="section" class="with_toggle">` remove  `class="with_toggle"` from your example site. You don't need to add that class in HTML, it will be added only by script. And everything will work prefect, just tested. If the answer was useful - don't forget to upvote it and check as accepted.

Comment: Oh yeeeeeessssss it works !!!!! 
Wonderfuuuuullllllll Thank you very much focus.style, you've been of great help :-)))
I wish you the best :)

Comment: Yes of course :-))
I have just implemented it in 2 of my site's pages, you can have a look here https://www.lepointdufle.net/ressources_fle/accord_des_adjectifstest.htm (Exercice 1 / Exercice 2 ) and I am afraid I can't use it because of the loading time which make the aside menu appear and doesn't give a very good experience I think.
I was wondering if you knew maybe an other solution ? Or should I just drop the idea ?
Thanks you for your advice

Comment: Place this right after `#section` block in HTML
`<script>
if (localStorage.toggled != '') {
  // set class to #section form storage value
  document.getElementById("section").classList.toggle(localStorage.toggled);
}
</script>`

and there will be no blinking effect. Try it and tell if it's OK

Comment: I moved the .js right after the <body> with no big difference. Is that what you mean ?

Comment: I mean not the separate JS file, but Javascript inside HTML. As i said, try to place this code in HTML `<script> if (localStorage.toggled != '') {   // set class to #section form storage value   document.getElementById("section").classList.toggle(localStorage.toggled); } </script>`

Comment: You can keep separate JS file. Just add some more code to right to HTML.

Comment: Are you using some backend, like PHP?

Comment: Ooohh yes it works !! You are my angel :-))
No php, only html. I started this site for 18 years ago, but sometimes I thing it would be useful

Comment: Dear focus.style :-) 
I have now implemented your system all over my site and I am sooooo happy :-))
Thank you again for your expertise and help.
I wish you the best.
Best regards,
Hélène

Comment: Great to hear that! Glad to help you!

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Just create a localStorage variable that keeps track of whether the shrink should be active and use that to apply your styles on page load or something similar.

```
function shrinkActive() {
  var shrink;
  if (!(shrink = localStorage.getItem("shrink"))) {
    localStorage.setItem("shrink", "false");
    return false;
  }

  return JSON.parse(shrink);
}

function setShrink(active) {
  var element1 = document.getElementById("one1");
  var element2 = document.getElementById("two1");
  
  if (active) {
    element1.classList.add("one2");
    element2.classList.add("two2");
  } else {
    element1.classList.remove("one2");
    element2.classList.remove("two2");
  }
  
  localStorage.setItem("shrink", active.toString());
}

function myFunction() {
  setShrink(!shrinkActive());
}

window.onload = function() {
  setShrink(shrinkActive());
}
```

Link to working Codepen. https://codepen.io/bugcatcher9000/pen/pogZbrz?editors=1111

Comment: Nice one, but mine is shorter and a bit optimized. Try to use code Snippet or Codepan, to increase the quality of the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer !! Unfortunatelly it doesn't shrink anymore, I might have forgotten something. And I found the solution in the answer above.
Thanks again, I wish you the best :-)